# Spark dataframe explode pair of lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

My dataframe has 2 columns which look like this:

```
col_id| col_name
-----------
id1   | name1
id2   | name2
------------
id3   | name3
id4   | name4
....
```

so for each row, there are 2 matching arrays of the same length in columns id and name. What I want is to get each pair of id/name as a separate row like:

```
col_id| col_name
-----------
id1   | name1
-----------
id2   | name2
....
```

`explode` seems like the function to use but I can't seem to get it to work. What I tried is:

```
rdd.explode(col("col_id"), col("col_name")) ({
case row: Row =>
  val ids: java.util.List[String] = row.getList(0)
  val names: java.util.List[String] = row.getList(1)

  var res: Array[(String, String)] = new Array[(String, String)](ids.size)
  for (i <- 0 until ids.size) {
    res :+ (ids.get(i), names.get(i))
  }
  res
})
```

This however returns only nulls so it might just be my poor knowledge of Scala. Can anyone point out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the last 10mins out of the past 1-2hours did the trick lol. This works just fine:

```
df.explode(col("id"), col("name")) ({
case row: Row =>
  val ids: List[String] = row.getList(0).asScala.toList
  val names: List[String] = row.getList(1).asScala.toList

  ids zip names
})
```